# Handle Double-click Mouse Event and Return Pressed for NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

OK, what I need is pretty straightforward, though I can still find nothing specific.

I want to be able to :

- track double-click events
- track when the `NSTableView` is in focus, and the "Return" key is pressed.

How would you go about it?

P.S. I've had a look into `NSTableViewDelegate` specification, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Why you want to focus return key? Do you need to set new value to table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For double click you need to do just these :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [self.tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(thisMethod)];
    //And if you wish to take selector dynamically, I guess you know how to do :)
}

-(void)thisMethod{
    NSLog(@"double clicked");
}
```

Comment: Yup that's 100% right. (Oh, I must have used this one in the past but ... forgotten all about it... lol). As for "Return" key-handling, it's not about editting values. I'm using a `NSTableView` *inside* a custom `NSView` which shows like an **Autocompletion** dropdown, inside a custom editor. If the user's focus is on the editor, then everything's handle by the editor class and everything is fine. But, if the focus goes to the dropdown, the return key (a.k.a. "Do something with the currently selected value" = "Insert in the editor, at cursor position") must be handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

For the return event, subclass your NSTableView and override keyDown:

Swift 5.x:

```swift
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if event.characters?.count == 1 {
            let character = event.keyCode
            switch (character) {
            // 36 is return
            case UInt16(36):
                print("return: \(event)")
            default:
                print("any other key: \(event)")
            }
        } else {
            super.keyDown(with: event)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to handle the Return key without having to manually check for its key code.
I'll show the answer in Swift, but it can be applied in Objective-C as well.

First, override `keyDown(with:)` in your view controller subclass that controls the table view and call `interpretKeyEvents(_:)`:

```swift
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    interpretKeyEvents([event])
}
```

Second, in the same view controller subclass, override `insertNewLine(_:)`. This is called when the user presses the Return key:

```swift
override func insertNewLine(_ sender: Any?) {
    // Add your logic to handle the Return key being pressed
}
```

Here's an example:

```swift
class TableViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        interpretKeyEvents([event])
    }

    override func insertNewLine(_ sender: Any?) {
        guard tableView.selectedRow >= 0 else { return }
        print("Pressed Return on row \(tableView.selectedRow)")
    }
}
```